# Installing Poco library on VS2010

Tags: installation, poco-libraries

I'm trying to use Poco library in VS2010 without any success.

I've downloaded poco-1.4.1p1.zip to my computer, unzipped it and moved it into my Program Files folder.

After doing that, tried to add this folder to my project additional include directories (this is at Properties (right click on the project) -> Configuration Properties -> C\C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories ).

This have not helped to the situation as lines in my program like

> ## include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"

are still marked as an error saying

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
> file: 'Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h': No
> such file or directory

This is my first time trying to add an external library to VS2010. I've tried to get help on the MSDN documentation and the POCO documentation site without success.

Also, I've came across some turms like system variables not once in my search. What does it mean?

Finally, can you help me get Poco library running?

Thanks in advance,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0):

You must first build POCO using Visual Studio or the Visual Studio command line component.

See the instructions here: http://poco.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/poco/poco/branches/poco-1.4.1/README